# Rails auth without any gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I did my own auth like on my old php site, I use sessions for that and md5 hash for pass. My session after auth look like that:

```
{"session_id"=>"874e2703dbaa562da8350fe141612cb6", "_csrf_token"=>"o3g5VHz7f6BPCwpaphI/7qnBnaDVBcguKVB4lXqvUss=", "user_id"=>2, "login"=>"123", "avatar"=>/uploads/resume/avatar/2/avatars/noava.jpg, "group_id"=>1}
```

All other things are done, but Now how I can to restrict the access for different  actions in my controller depending on my session ?

Or can I fix this with devise and cancan gems? They are using bcrypt, but my old passwords in md5 and i cant use for that bcrypt.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the ideas of authentication and authorization.

You've built your own authentication - you know who people are. Devise is an example of a gem that handles authentication.

Authorization controls what people can do, and is completely independent of authentication. Cancan is an example of a gem that handles authorization.

Use Cancan, or anything [here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization).